# I want to take some files from a feature branch and move changes to another branch

Tags: git

I've been working on a feature branch and have made changes to UI files and logic/data files, and have added them in various commits - often with changes to many files in each commit.

I've decided that I want to make a branch with just the logic changes in it, so I can merge that to master so that other team members can use it, while I work on UI bits myself.

I basically want to create a new branch from master, and then add the changes from select files in my feature branch (not select commits, but select files). Is this something that can be done?

For added clarity:

My feature branch looks like this -

Commit 1:

- fileA.js
- fileB.js

Commit 2:

- fileA.js
- fileC.js

Commit 3

- fileC.js
- fileD.js

And I want to end up with a new feature branch that has -

Commit 1:

- fileB.js
- fileD.js

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do here, just create a new branch and commit out outside of the master branch?

Comment: @JoshStevens I've already made days of changes on a feature branch, I basically want to separate the changes though into two separate feature branches, based on files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given exactly what you are asking for (to create a *single* commit containg all the changes from *some* files) you want to:

1. Create a new branch off `master`: `git branch <feature/new> master`
2. Checkout the branch: `git checkout <feature/new>`
3. Checkout the wanted files from the old feature branch to the new one:
   `git checkout <feature/old> -- <files to checkout>`.

I feel like this is one of the less well know uses of `git checkout`. It pulls just the wanted files to your current branch without changing branch.
([Git documentation on this usage of checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203))

**Bonus points:** if, some some reason, a file has changes that you both need and don't need you can utilise the even more obscure `--patch` option (`git checkout --patch <feature/old> -- <files to checkout>`). This option invokes the interactive picker, which allows you to select specific hunks to include. The interactive mode can get some getting use to, but is helpful when you need to split things apart. It also exists on the add and reset command.
([Git's documentation on Interactive mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_interactive_mode))

Comment: I did not know you could use `git checkout` like that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

1. Start your logic branch where your current feature branch is at: `git checkout -b feature_logic feature`
2. Rewind your history, preserving the current state of the files. I am making the assumption the `master` branch has not been moved during the development of your feature: `git reset --soft origin/master`. Or if it is really just three commits: `git reset --soft HEAD^^^`
3. Un-stage and revert the files you **do not** want as part of the `feature_logic` branch: `git reset HEAD -- <files>` and `git checkout -- <files>`
4. Run `git status` to ensure that the correct files are staged.
5. Commit the logic branch: `git commit -m"Logic branch"`

Repeat the above steps for the gui branch.
After creating your two new branches, you should be able to merge them, and run `git diff HEAD..feature` to make yourself feel good that nothing has been lost in the history rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you can do `git reset HEAD~3`, this will reset all the commits.

Now, you can segregate all the files related to logic and UI.

Make separate commit for both in a different branch.